# A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (Html="<!DOCTYPE html PUBLI...") asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am using iTextSharp to use a function and convert HTML to PDF to do it from an icon I call a function in my controller sending the html string as a parameter when doing so I get an error I wanted to know if anyone knows how I can fix it.

> Error

A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (Html="<!DOCTYPE html PUBLI...")

> View

```
@foreach (var item in Model.RecordEntries) {

 <a target="_blank" validateRequest="false" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="@Url.Action("Export", "Home" , new { item.Html })"> <i class="fas fa-eye"> </i></a>
}
```

> Controller

```
      [HttpPost]
      [ValidateInput(false)]
      public FileResult Export(string GridHtml)
      {
          using (MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
          {
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(GridHtml);
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "Grid.pdf");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the validation of your request by encoding input data. Try to do it the following way:

```
string encodedString = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["name"]);
```

Or as an alternative option, you can add reset **validateRequest** parameter in web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" 
      validateRequest="false"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

However, this approach will make you application more vulnerable to different kind of attacks.